# Codeigniter Edit (Check Duplicate + Allow to Update if duplicate not found)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Check For Duplicate on Edit Function

Currently my DB table

```
USERDB
userId userName userPassword userEmail userAddress userPhone
```

What I want

> Allow to check on "userName" duplication" and if "userName" return
>   true , then it allow to edit other textfield.

Problem Met:

> When i did not change anything on my "userName" field , and i edited
>   userEmail, it will always return FALSE due to my "userName" is
>   duplicate with current DB data.

```
$checkvalidation = $this->userdb->UsernameDuplicatechecking($userName);
if($checkvalidation == TRUE){
$this->userdb->updateUser($userName,$userEmail,$userAddress,$userPhone,$id);
}else{
  $this->session->set_flashdata('errormessage', 'Duplicate');
  redirect("User/EditUserAccount/$id");
  }
```

Update Model Code

```
public function updateUser($userName,$userEmail,$userAddress,$userPhone,$id);
{
    $UserArray = array(
                    'userName' => $userName,
                    'userEmail' => $userEmail,
                    'userAddress' => $userAddress,
                    'userPhone' => $userPhone,                  
                  );


    $this->db->set($UserArray);
    $this->db->where('userId',$id);
    $this->db->update('USERDB');        
}
```

Comment: you have to add contrition in checking user duplicate that userid != currentuserid

Comment: use form validation method

Comment: you just updating the value not insert a new value,During inserting the value only check the duplication of value in the database.you going update the value only why you checking the duplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem you have to send user ID in which function you can check duplicate's of user name.

```
$this->userdb->UsernameDuplicatechecking($userName,$id);
```

After sending user ID to function ***UsernameDuplicatechecking*** . Add a where condition the userID is not equal to this current ID.

```
$this->db->where("userId <> $id");
```

I hope this will sort out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the user can edit their information I am assuming they are logged in. In which case you need to get their current username from the session or wherever and perform something like:

Pseudo-code:

```
if ($isNotDuplicate || $postedUsername == $sessOrDbUsername) {

    // update

}
```

This way when the user just wants to edit their details and the form submits with their username being the same as the one they have aka duplicate we can simply do another check to determine if their current username is the same as the one with the post request. If it is, we continue with update.